# How convert bson byte array to string with java?

Tags: java, json, jackson, arrays, bson

I am using [bson4jackson](http://www.michel-kraemer.com/binary-json-with-bson4jackson) for parsing bson. Everything works fine until a get invalid byte array. Is it possible to decode byte array to string? Suppose client send me json `{"request":31}` but some bytes are lost and I get mailformed byte array which corresponds to json like that `{"request`. Is there a way to parse bson into string to see what element are lost?

Comment: Although I think that wasn't the question (You should think about reframing/reformatting it): "decode" `byte[]` to `String` should simply work with it's constructor (`public String(byte[] bytes)`)

Comment: But bson format is not just `string.getBytes`, no?